# Correctly Calculate Cost Based on Units Percentage

Tags: ms-project

I have an 8-month project am I planning. It's a software development project with 11 developers (and many other resources). I count "Devs" as one resource item, rather than Dev1, Dev2, Dev3 etc. On the "Devs" line in the resource sheet, I set the Max units to 1100% and set a per-hour rate in Std.Rate.

My expectation is that: when I assign 1100% of the "Dev" resource to a 5-day task in the Gantt Chart, it's 1100% (or 11) * the hourly rate.

However the cost against the resource in the task resources tab nor the cost reports reflect this. They reflect 1 "Dev" costs rather than my 11 Devs. Also, in the resource usage view, the hours still reflect the total hours for 1 developer, not 11.

I'm missing something, I assume, to allow for MS Project to calculate the cost / hours based on unit percentage?

Comment: Hi @Damo, it's a good practice to not write tags in title because Stack's tag system is good and we should trust it. See more here: meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/364217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the total work for the task remained the same (40 hrs). The cost is dependent on how much work the resource(s) are doing which is not always the same as the duration of the task. Typically, when more resources are added to a task, the duration shortens to keep the work the same.

Insert the [Work](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.work), [Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.type), and [Effort Driven](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.effortdriven) fields into your Gantt table to review the values.

Here is more information about these settings: [Change the effort driven setting for task types](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-effort-driven-setting-for-task-types-18efd7c7-d146-4b06-bdbe-b6a11564bdf3)